# Powells Method for 2 Variables?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, optimization, combinatorics, search-algorithms

I've been studying [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/juADgFL_B8c) on Powells method and it looks like when we have a single variable we start at the upper and lower bounds of the variable and then we keep dividing the search space until we find the minimum.

So for a single variable it looks pretty easy.  How do we do it for 2 variables?

Does anyone have a simple example of how to iterate through the algorithm?

For example suppose we have $F(X_1, X_2)$ and $X_1$ can range between 0 and 6 and $X_2$ between 0 and 4.

After the first iteration we determine that we need to focus $X_1$ between 0 and 3 and $X_2$ between 2 and 4.

I assume that we plugged in $F(X_1=1.5, X_2=1), F(X_1=1.5, X_2=3), F(X_1=4.5, X_2=1), F(X_1=4.5, X_2=3)$

And that we found out that the superior point was the $F(X_1=1.5, X_2=3)$, and so now we repeat.

Is that about right?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powell%27s_method

Comment: OK - I think I'm starting to get it.  IIUC the golden section search is used to find the optimal point within each starting plane.  And then we move to that coordinate and repeat?